# Why can't PHP locate the file?

Tags: php, variables

Why won't the following code work? I'm a bit fuzzy on some of my PHP, as it has been a few months since I've done much with it.

```
<?php include 'connect.php';
?>
<?php
if (file_exists($Theme_directory."'/".$Theme_current."/header.php"))
    {
        echo '<p>It exists.</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p>It does not exist.</p>';
    }
?>
```

The variables used in my connect.php file are below:

```
//CloudBurst Info
//If you mess with these, make sure that you are changing the directories, as well.
$Theme_directory ='themes';
$Theme_current ='default';
```

When I can get it to recognize the file, which does exist at themes/default/header.php, I will have it included.

Comment: `"'/"` looks like a typo to me ...did you mean `"/"` ?

Comment: Probably the apostrophe in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `'` in your path.  Try the following:

```
if (file_exists($Theme_directory."/".$Theme_current."/header.php"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "'/" (an apostrophe) where it should be "/" in your file_exists path.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the concatenation it becomes more obvious:

```
"$Theme_directory'/$Theme_current/header.php"
                 ^
```

The fix is trivial:

```
"$Theme_directory/$Theme_current/header.php"
```